# Concerning the Countable-Closed Topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

**I am required to prove the following proposition**. The following is my attempt thus far. Is it correct?

**Proposition.**  Let $X$ be any infinite set. The **countable-closed topology** is defined to be the topology having as its closed sets $X$ and all countable subsets of $X$. Prove that this is indeed a topology on $X$.

**Proof.** Let $\tau$ denote the supposed topology in question. Since $\varnothing$ is countable and therefore closed, it follows that $X$ is open. In addition from hypothesis $X$ is closed, implying that $\varnothing$ is open.

Now let $\{\mathcal{A}_j:j\in J\}$ collection of sets in $\tau$, indexed by some set $J$. We prove that $\bigcup_{j\in J}\mathcal{A}_j\in \tau$. Consider that $ \bigcap_{j\in J}X\backslash A_j = X\backslash\left(\bigcup_{j\in J}\mathcal{A}_j\right)$. It is therefore sufficient to show that the set $ \bigcap_{j\in J}X\backslash A_j$ is countable and therefore closed in $\tau$.

Now the set $\bigcap_{j\in J}X\backslash A_j$ maybe either finite, in which case we are done or infinite in which we proceed as follows. Let $j_0\in J$, the set $\mathcal{A}_{j_0}\in\tau$, thus $X\backslash\mathcal{A}_{j_0}$ is closed and therefore countable. Thus we have a bijection $H:\mathcal{A}_{j_0}\to\mathbf{N}$,   restricting the domain of $H$ to the set $\bigcap_{j\in J}X\backslash A_j$ yields the required bijection between $\bigcap_{j\in J}X\backslash A_j$ and $\mathbf{N}$, proving that $\bigcap_{j\in J}X\backslash A_j$ is countable.

---

I am struggling to prove that $A_1\cap A_2\in\tau$ whenever $A_1,A_2\in \tau$ any suggestions here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show that $X \setminus (A_1 \cap A_2) = (X \setminus A_1) \cup(X \setminus A_2)$ is countable.  By hypothesis that $A_1,A_2 \in \tau$, $X \setminus A_1$ and $X \setminus A_2$ are countable.  From [elementary-set-theory](/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory), we have $\aleph_0 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$, where $\aleph_0 = \mathop{\rm{card}}(\Bbb{N})$.  Therefore, $$\mathop{\rm{card}}(X \setminus (A_1 \cap A_2)) = \mathop{\rm{card}}((X \setminus A_1) \cup(X \setminus A_2)) \\ \le \mathop{\rm{card}}(X \setminus A_1)+\mathop{\rm{card}}(X \setminus A_2) = \aleph_0 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0.$$  Hence $X \setminus (A_1 \cap A_2)$ is countable and $A_1\cap A_2 \in \tau$.

Comment: Is there a way we can do this without resorting to cardinal Arithematic?

Comment: @AtifFarooq For a [tag:general-topology] course, you don't need that.  I put them for the sake of rigor.  Simply stating that "a finite union of countable sets is countable" is enough.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.